# Regex for extracting character groups ends with number and follows by a special pattern

Tags: regex, postgresql, match

I want to extract table.%%columnname%% info from a free text like below

```
GET_INFO(CUSTOMER1.%%NAME%%='TEST' AND CREDIT1.%%AMOUNT%%>1000)=1
```

The output i need is

```
CUSTOMER1.%%NAME%%
CREDIT1.%%AMOUNT%%
```

I have tried `[a-zA-Z*][0-9].\%%.*?\%%` but it didnt give me the output i need

Comment: Replace `[a-zA-Z*]` with `[a-zA-Z]*` and escape the `.`

Comment: Actually i am executing this on postgres. SELECT array_to_string((regexp_matches('GET_INFO(CUSTOMER1.%%NAME%%=''TEST'' AND CREDIT1.%%AMOUNT%%>1000)=1', '[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]\.\%%.*?\%%','g')),'') and this does not give the output i needed

Comment: Try `([a-zA-Z*0-9]+)\.\%\%.*?\%\%` (assuming you have to escape the `%`). Depending on what flavour of RegEx PostgreSQL uses you could adapt the RegEx in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/kqNe5e/3) to suit your purposes.

Comment: What about `'[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]\.%%[^%]*%%'`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+\.%%[^%]*%%
```

*Details*:

- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more letters (`[[:alpha:]]*` can also be used here)
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `%%`  - `%%` string
- `[^%]*` - any zero or more chars other than a `%` char
- `%%`  - `%%` string

Comment: Shouldn't it be "one or more chars" for `columnname`, i.e. `[^%]+`, assuming character names are allowed?

Comment: @Inigo Since it is extraction of the whole pattern here, I think using `+` or `*` does not matter much here. If the part was captured, it would make more sense to use `+`.